# PHP script not finishing its job

Tags: php, upload, xmlhttprequest

I have a web page where I am POSTing 2 images to a php script from a canvas through xmlhttprequest. If I wait for the 2 separate requests to finish everything is ok but if I navigate away from the page after the first one finished uploading the second one just doesn't do anything I guess it simply stops.

My questions is do I have to keep the page open until both uploads are finished? I thought if an xmlhttprequest is started it will finish no matter what, even if you close the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the xmlhttprequest is bound to the page you are currently on.

Add a callback to show the user when the process completes.

Comment: I thought so just wasn't sure. Is there any other way to upload something without having to wait for it to finish?

Comment: @slash197 short answer, no. You can't do a "partial upload", or you could do it, but you'll receive a "partial content" on the server side...

Answer (score 0):

Well could it be that you go away from the page while you are still uploading the image? (if the image is quite big it could take a while to upload it completely) in that case you are stopping the upload and probably the page php that manage the end of the upload doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

As said by symcbean, all `XMLHttpRequest` are bound to your current page. So if you change the page or if you close the tab or the browser, all currently running request will be aborted.

> I thought if an xmlhttprequest is started it will finish no matter what, even if you close the browser.

Do you like if, when you close an application, it doesn't really close it and the application would still running on the computer ?

Comment: Well, not quite like that. More like a php script, you can start it from a webpage through an ajax call, navigate away from that page and the script would still run (if it hasn't finished its job) on the server side.